# Edit sitemap in google search console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap

i have put the sitemap URL into the google seach console, however the sitemap that the website generates is really bad (full of sites that are only visible after signing in as an admin) and I can not change that behaviour.

Is there a way to manually remove these in the search console?

Comment: Why can't you change the sitemap?  It is your site.

Comment: Yes, you can delete the sitemap in GSC. It also sounds like you should turn off that feature and just generate a sitemap with an external software and upload it to your server.